# C# Decimal to Numeric(?,?)

Tags: c#, .net, ssis, decimal, numeric

I have a problem, i didn't found yet the solution so i am asking your help.
In my database I have some int, decimal and string that needs to be convert in numeric with specific length and precision to include in a flat file.

ex:

```
integer 123 to numeric(8,0) ==> 00000123
decimal 123,123 to numeric(8,8) ==> 0000012312300000
String "22" to numeric(8,0) ==> 00000022
```

It can't put comma or dot. Is there an easy solution
I try a lot of things but none will give me my result except doing loops foreach Filed in my flat file too dirty!!

EDIT:

the flat file gets information based on there start point and the lenght so every data i includ in the file has to be a cetain lenght. And for the Numeric I have for exemple

```
   database Decimal Price = 123,456
   File     Numeric(8,6) Price = 00000123456000
```

I wanted to know how could i parse any decimal or integer data based on N(*,*)

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense.  Please clarify what you are trying to achieve.  You should probably be using string.Format for this.

Comment: No need to downvote a question just because it's unclear, folks.

Comment: No need not to, either... people can downvote for whatever reason they want to :)

Comment: Am I more clear? sorry for the bad spelling I m french and even my french sucks :D

Comment: @Sander, sure they can, doesn't mean I can't encourage them not to though. ;)

Comment: The downvote button actually says "this question is unclear".

Comment: Call it a difference in ideologies then. ;)

Comment: @Polo: J'aime beaucoup ton comment "Am I more clear? sorry for the bad spelling I m french and even my french sucks :D" qui n'a pas un français poche... c bien trop compliqué ;P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
string ToNumericString(int value) {
    return value.ToString("00000000");
}

string ToNumericString(decimal value) {
    var value16 = Math.Truncate(value * 100000000);
    return value16.ToString("0000000000000000");
}

string ToNumericString(string value) {
    return ToNumericString(int.Parse(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}
```

To call it:

```
    MessageBox.Show(ToNumericString(123));
    MessageBox.Show(ToNumericString(123.123M));
    MessageBox.Show(ToNumericString("22"));
```

or more general:

```
string ToNumericString(decimal value, int digitsBefore, int digitsAfter) {
    var value16 = Math.Truncate(value * (decimal)Math.Pow(10,digitsAfter));
    return value16.ToString(new String('0', digitsBefore + digitsAfter));
}

MessageBox.Show(ToNumericString(123.123M, 8, 3));
```

Comment: how could it put "0" befor and after my value? decimal 123,123 to numeric(8,8) ==> 0000012312300000

Comment: @Polo In example above, I did it by adding eight 0s to the number (multiply with 100000000) and then converting it to string with sixteen 0 characters. That produces desired result (test it).
Other way you could do it is converting number before and after . separately. That would give you same result as first method but with little bit more clarity.

Comment: I've seen your exemple but i m trying to edit it because i have to choose the lenght sometime they want an N(8,3) or N(13,0) or N(9,3)

Comment: @Polo: I added more general example.

Answer (score 3):

Check out `String.Format`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx